# How to show each year-quarter in x-axis in the time plot generated by ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use ggplot to generate time plot by each year-quarter, but only years are shown on the x-axis. Q1, Q2, Q3,Q4 all missing? How to solve this problem.

```
> head(X02_4m_bb)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
   Year Quarter Revenue   CGS Gross_Profit_M Disp_Income_B YQ       
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl> <yearqtr>
1  1995       1   1275. 1080.           195.        16351. 1995 Q1  
2  1995       2   1438. 1228.           210.        16481. 1995 Q2  
3  1995       3   1929. 1672.           257.        16695. 1995 Q3  
4  1995       4   2576. 2246.           329.        16865. 1995 Q4  
5  1996       1   1637. 1387.           250.        17122. 1996 Q1  
6  1996       2   1779. 1510.           268.        17400. 1996 Q2  

ggplot(X02_4m_bb, aes(x=YQ, y=Revenue, group=1)) +
   geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: If it's just about labels on the x-axis this might provide some ideas: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the scales with for example `scale_x_date_yq`. 
Here is a working example:

```
require(zoo)
set.seed(314)

dates <- expand.grid(year = 1990:1995, q = 1:4) %>%
  mutate(YQ = as.yearqtr(paste0(year,' Q',q)))

  data.frame(YQ = dates$YQ,
         value = rnorm(nrow(dates))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = YQ, y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_yearqtr(breaks = dates$YQ) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1, vjust = 1))
```

[image]